# Activate FNLock on Lenovo X1 under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, thinkpad

On my Lenovo Thinkpad X1, the F-keys have the special functions (volume/brightness/...) as default. I do not want to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>, every time I need some actual F-key.

The problem is, I cannot activate FnLock under Ubuntu.
It should work with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, but doesn't. It did so under Windows. One solution I found said to fix it in BIOS, but under "Setting -> Keyboard" I have no setting for that.

Any idea where the problem can lie and how to fix it?

Comment: What generation of X1? My TP X1 4th generation and using Windows 10 sets it in BIOS. Different Generations might be different. The setting reverses what the base keys are.

Comment: It's 3rd Gen. And the Windows on the machine is gone for now.

Comment: I cannot find conclusively if there is a toggle in BIOS. There is fourth generation and beyond.